# Curved background in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to learn how to do a background with a curve like the one in the attached image, using HTML/CSS, any ideas?[image]

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: ofcourse i searched first, haven't found any good answers on google, i tried with border-radius, i tried with cubic bezier curves and svg drawing, didn't get a good result, i don't have a solid start point of code to share it, i do need help directed to the right path in finding the answer.

Comment: `clip-path` - start there.

Answer (score 1):

Started researching from clip-path, as suggested by @Paulie_D , that didn't do exactly what i wanted but it lead me to svg's, after a lot of reading and searching i found an answer, i'd like to share it, might be useful for anyone looking for something similar, here it is:

```
<div class="container">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="Gradient1" x1="0" x2="1" y1="0" y2="1">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#5ae7bd"/>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#2cd5ce"/>
      </linearGradient>
      </defs>
    <path d="M0,90 C150,25 350,150 500,80 L500,00 L0,0 Z" style="stroke: none; fill:url(#Gradient1);"></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```